# How to (gevent) spawn tasks without waiting for it to join

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, gevent

I have wrote a sample code of my problem. I am generating a random string and a shuffle function which adds a delay to a message so it comes out in a different order.

However, the scheduled task only executes once I have `joinall` at the end. Is there a way to execute the scheduling and tasks while dynamically scheduling new spawning ones. When I keep pressing enter, it schedules a new task but it doesn't execute until I have reached the random condition I have set. But, if I put the `join/joinall` after the append, it will block. Is this possible to do with gevent or what else libraries can this be done with any other asynchronous I/O or non-blocking libraries or do I have to resort to multithreading.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import random 
import string
from gevent import sleep, spawn, joinall

def random_string():
    digits = "".join( [random.choice(string.digits) for i in xrange(8)] )
    chars = "".join( [random.choice(string.letters) for i in xrange(10)] )
    return chars

def delay_message(message, delay):
    sleep(delay)
    print("Shuffled message: {} and time: {}". format(message, delay))

def main():
    while True:
        s = raw_input("Please continue pressing enter, messages will appear when they are ready")
        if s == "":
            delay = random.randint(0, 10)
            string = random_string()
            print("Message: {} and time: {}". format(string, delay))
            tasks = []
            tasks.append(spawn(delay_message, string, delay))

            if (random.randint(0,10) == 5): # random condition in breaking
                joinall(tasks, raise_error=True)
                break
        else:
            print("Exiting")
            break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `raw_input` is a *blocking* operating system call. gevent is cooperative, so when the main greenlet is stuck in `raw_input` *no other greenlet can run*. Is this your actual code you have a problem with or have you simplified it to include `raw_input`?

Comment: @JasonMadden Instead of `raw_input`, it would be `sock.recv()` and instead of printing at delay_message, I would `sendall()`. Would that still pose a problem?

Comment: Unless you've either monkey-patched the system very early on, or are specifically importing and using gevent's socket class, yes, those would still be blocking calls that would lead to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: Use ThreadPool e.g. `tasks = ThreadPool(25)` that is assigned outside the loop and remove `tasks=[]` and the `joinall()`

Also, add `from gevent import wait` then add `wait()` in the random condition in the while loop before the break, so that existing tasks can finish before the program is exited

Comment: so if you monkeypatch, normal things become gevent yielding events like, sleep and io reads...

Answer (score 0):

Specifically the work will get done whether or not you join, you only need to join when you need to be sure the work is done before you move on to insure concurrency, you can use lots of methods to get status as you are going along (queues, shared variable, callbacks, delegate methods), since you are using greenlets you don't even really need to lock atomic operations like adding numbers, because they are happening on the same thread.